# Form Input Value not updating from script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a text input as follows:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control assetID" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Asset ID" name="assetID[]"></td>
```

and a script that runs when the first input field is modified. I would like to update the value of the 2nd input when this script runs:

```
 $this.closest('tr').children('.form-control.assetID').val(assetID);
```

with the value of the asset variable. I can't get the form input to update here when this script runs and can't see the issue here? I will have a series of similar inputs that are added dynamically so I'm not using an id for these but targeting them by the class.

Here's an example of my table/scripts:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    var markup = "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control serialNumber\" autocomplete=\"off\" placeholder=\"Serial Number\" name=\"serialNumber[]\" value=\"\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control assetID\" autocomplete=\"off\" placeholder=\"Asset ID\" name=\"assetID[]\" value=\"\"></td></td><td class=\"productCode\"></td><td class=\"description\"></td><td class=\"text-center deleteRow\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></td></tr>";
    $("#shipmentItems").append(markup);
  });

  // Find and remove selected table rows

  $("#shipmentItems").on("click", ".deleteRow", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});




$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.form-control.serialNumber', function() {

    var serialNumber = $(this).val();
    //console.log( recid );
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);

    ID = 'ABC123';
    code = 'PC8765';
    description = 'Acme Standard Widget';

    $this.closest('tr').children('.form-control.assetID').val(ID);
    $this.closest('tr').children('.code').html(code);
    $this.closest('tr').children('.description').html(description);

  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="shipmentItems" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="20%">Serial</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="15%">Code</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="45%">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col" width="5%"></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>



    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control serialNumber" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Serial Number" name="serialNumber[]" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control assetID" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Asset ID" name="assetID[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="code"></td>
      <td class="description"></td>
      <td class="deleteRow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" name="addRow" value="addRow" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary">Add Asset</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

When I change the first column I would like the values in the other columns to be updated.

Comment: The selector is wrong. It should be `.form-control.assetID`

Comment: I've updated it to `$this.closest('tr').children('.form-control.assetID').val(assetID);` but the input is not being updated when the script runs. It is updating the other non input table cells and I can see the assetID in the console with the correct value.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a sample of the table and script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not this

```
.children('.form-control assetID')
```

But this

```
.children('.form-control.assetID')
```

Explanation: Selecting element with 2 classes requires to not keep space between both classes , also prefixing both classes by `.`

Comment: I've updated it to `$this.closest('tr').children('.form-control.assetID').val(assetID);` but the input is not being updated. The other table cells are but they are not inputs. Anything else I can look at here?

Comment: Run `console.log($this.closest('tr'))` and check in the console is it the desired element

Comment: ran that and confirmed that it is the desired element here